# Powershell saída de arquivo .CSV apos Foreach

Tags: csv, powershell, tcp, telnet

Boa tarde!
Eu tenho um scritp simples em powershell que realiza o teste de conexão entre domains controllers e suas respectivas portas de serviços conforme a baixo:

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\DC Health\Domains_Controllers.txt'
$IP_TCPs = Get-Content -Path 'C:\DC Health\TCP_Ports.txt'
foreach($IP_TCP in $IP_TCPs){
foreach($server in $servers){

$socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.tcpClient

Try{
    $socket.Connect($server, $IP_TCP)
Write-Host $server $IP_TCP Conectado
}
Catch{
Write-Host $server $IP_TCP Desconectado
}

Finally{
    $socket.Close()
    $socket.Dispose()

}
}
}
```

Queria ter a saída em algum arquivo como .txt ou .csv, porem o arquivo sempre sai em branco.
Existe alguma possibilidade de alteração ou acrescentar para esta saída?
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerta: Testes realizados no windows 10 com powershell 5.1.

Aviso: "Write-Host" não redireciona para arquivo e sim para a console.

Dica: A utilização da cláusula "Try" deve ser evitada pois afeta o objeto "$Error". Sempre que possível, utilize comandos que testem a situação. No seu caso em particular, você poderia usar "Test-NetConnection"

Então, eu trocaria o código interno para:

```
$Resposta = ( Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port $IP_TCP ).TcpTestSucceeded
$Objeto = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Servidor = $server
    PortaTCP = $IP_TCP
    Situação = @( 'Desconectado', 'Conectado' )[ [Boolean]$Resposta ]
}
Export-Csv -InputObject $Objeto -LiteralPath '[caminho]\[nome do arquivo].csv' -Append
```

Agora, respondendo seu questionamento:

1) Antes da cláusula "Try", crie um objeto personalizado:

```
$Objeto = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Servidor = $server
    PortaTCP = $IP_TCP
    Situação = ''
}
```

2) Depois da chamada do soquete:

2.1) Atualize o objeto:

```
$Objeto.Situação = 'Conectado'
```

2.2) Remova a cláusula "Write-Host"

3) Na cláusula "Catch":

3.1) Atualize o objeto:

```
$Objeto.Situação = 'Desconectado'
```

3.2) Remova a cláusula "Write-Host"

4) Na cláusula "Finally", exporte o objeto para um arquivo CSV:

```
Export-Csv -InputObject $Objeto -LiteralPath '[caminho]\[nome do arquivo].csv' -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Para exportar o resultado diretamente para um arquivo de texto, pode usar o comando pipeline [Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7)

Exemplo de uso:

```
"$server $IP_TCP Conectado" | Out-File -FilePath "c:\\temp\\test.txt" -Append
```